# Dates showing up as 5 digits, not sure how to change them back to text

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

Not sure how to revert dates back to text, I looked everywhere but none of the other formulas worked, not sure if this is because of the concatenate/&

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv9bc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsLCp.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/flJ4Q.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of referring to the date cell directly try this:

```
=TEXT(E1,"mmm dd, yyyy")
```